# How do I create a subdomain on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, dns

I just want to add a couple subdomains to my computers FQDN so that I can have some Vitrual Servers (apache.)

Any ideas?

Note: I need to add the aliases to my machine, like a.foo.com and b.foo.com.  I don't think apache makes those aliases.

Alternative: I decided that instead of trying to add stuff to my domain name (since then I'd have to edit the dns server) I would configure virtual hosts for a separate port.  That way it's all up to my computer.  Thanks for the help nonetheless!

Comment: Are the virtual servers internal-only, or will they appear on the public internet?

Comment: do you mean moving "a.example.com" as "a.foo.int.example.com" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is on a Windows domain: go into the DNS management tool on the DC, and add host entries (CN records, not A records) pointing the desired names to the original computer name.

If you're doing this all on one (non-server) box: edit the hosts file, and point the names to the right IP address.